# How to get nicer TimeSpan object output?

Tags: c#

If I got such an output - `TimeSpan` object - how can I get it nicely without extra zeros and so many decimal places?

Comment: Try to clarify, what is the format that you need?

Comment: Can you give more details? Give an example of what you have now and what you want.

Answer (score 4):

This was fixed in .NET 4.0, the TimeSpan struct acquired a ToString() overload that lets you specify a format string.  If you cannot upgrade then you might consider this extension method:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static string Format(this TimeSpan ts, string format) {
        var dt = new DateTime(Math.Abs(ts.Ticks));
        var result = dt.ToString(format);
        if (ts.Ticks < 0) result = "-" + result;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
        var ts = new TimeSpan(1, 2, 3);
        var s = ts.Format("h:mm:ss");
```

Produces 1:02:03

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting .NET 4 you can use one of the format specifiers on the [`TimeSpan.ToString(string)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx)

Without knowing your exact requirements the "g" [TimeSpan Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx) might be what you need:

> General short format
>
> This specifier outputs only what is needed. It is culture-sensitive and takes the form
> `[-][d’:’]h’:’mm’:’ss[.FFFFFFF]`.

Comment: @Hans - I didn't spot that. I'll update the answer.